# Not check if user is taken

Tags: php, mysql

This snip of code doesn't do as it's supposed to and i can't see why. Please help

```
$userquery = "SELECT Username FROM Member WHERE Username = '$username'";
$checkUser = mysqli_num_rows($conn, $userquery);
if($checkUser > 0 ){
header("Location:Registration.php?UserError=true&reason=taken" );
}else{

$query = "INSERT INTO Member ( Username, Password, Email, Salt, Verify_Code ) VALUES
( '$username', '$password', '$email', '$salt', '$verify_code' )";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
}
```

Thanks people

Comment: Because it works as it should and your if check returns false?

Comment: Please tell me that you're escaping `$username`, `$password`, `$email`, `$salt` and `$verify_code`.

Comment: exit(); after the header redirect, or the rest of the code will run in the script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to execute your query `$Result =  mysqli_query ($conn , $query);`

```
   <?php 
       $userquery = "SELECT Username FROM Member WHERE Username = '$username'";        
       $Result =  mysqli_query ($conn , $query);
       $checkUser = mysqli_num_rows($Result);
       if($checkUser > 0 ){
        header("Location:Registration.php?UserError=true&reason=taken" );
       }else{

        $query = "INSERT INTO Member ( Username, Password, Email, Salt, Verify_Code ) VALUES
        ( '$username', '$password', '$email', '$salt', '$verify_code' )";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
       }

   ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Chinnu life saver ;)

Comment: NP. Glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$queryObj = mysqli_query($conn, $userquery);
$checkUser = mysqli_num_rows($conn, $queryObj);
```

You are not executing the query. you need to execute it first.